# How i can execute a callback function inside a callback function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two callback functions i want to execute one inside the other one,
heres the first one:

```
dealer.MeasuringUnit= function () {
        // alert("ss");

        var url = servername+'admin/measure/getMeasurings';
        // var url = 'http://localhost:8080/getFournisseurs';
        //$scope.startSpin('spinner-3');
        console.log("Inside getAutocarsActiveTrue " + url);

        function onSuccess(response) {
            console.log("+++++getAutocarsActiveTrue SUCCESS++++++");

            if (response.data.success != false) {
                console.log("Inside getAutocarsActiveTrue response..." + JSON.stringify(response.data));

                var measuring=response.data.data;
                //alert(JSON.stringify($scope.mapOptions));

                var elm=angular.element(document.querySelector('#measuring'));
                //elm.html("");
                for(var i=0;i<measuring.length;i++) {
                    var checkId = measuring[i].id;
                    var label = measuring[i].label;
                   // alert(checkId);
                    dealer.getMeasurByUnitId(checkId);

                        //alert("ko");
                        elm.append($compile(
                             '<label class="control-label">'
                            + label
                            + '</label>'
                            +'<select>'
                           + '<option ng-repeat="x in units">{{x.label}}</option>'
                            +'</select><br/>'
                        )($scope));
                    }



                //console.log($scope.countries);

            } else {
                alert("failure");
            }
            // $scope.stopSpin('spinner-3');
        };

        function onError(response) {
            console.log("-------getAutocarsActiveTrue FAILED-------");
            //$scope.stopSpin('spinner-3');
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log("Inside getAllBooks error condition...");
        };

        //----MAKE AJAX REQUEST CALL to GET DATA----
        ajaxServicess.getData(url,"admin","admin", 'GET', '').then(onSuccess, onError);

    };
```

the second one is :dealer.getMeasurByUnitId(checkId)

```
dealer.getMeasurByUnitId = function (id) {
        var url = servername+'admin/unite/getMeasuringByUnit/';
        // var url = 'http://localhost:8080/getFournisseurs';
        //$scope.startSpin('spinner-3');

        console.log("Inside getAutocarsActiveTrue " + url);

        function onSuccess(response) {
            console.log("+++++getAutocarsActiveTrue SUCCESS++++++");

            if (response.data.success != false) {
                console.log("Inside getAutocarsActiveTrue response..." + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                isGetUnitDone=true;
                $scope.units=response.data.data;
                console.log($scope.units);
                isGetUnitDone=true;
               // alert("ass");


            } else {
                alert("failure");
            }
            // $scope.stopSpin('spinner-3');
        };

        function onError(response) {
            console.log("-------getAutocarsActiveTrue FAILED-------");
            //$scope.stopSpin('spinner-3');
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log("Inside getAllBooks error condition...");
        };

        //----MAKE AJAX REQUEST CALL to GET DATA----
        ajaxServicess.getData(url,"admin","admin", 'GET', id).then(onSuccess, onError);

    };
```

the second one return an object  deponds pn an id return from the from function, but the problem is, in the final result, the select box displays just the last record returned from the second function, how to fix this problem?

Comment: You want to execute the second function after the first succeeded ? do you need your first function results to start the second ? If yes, take a look at [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: It is hard to write an answer about chaining promises when the example is polluted with a success handler building DOM. AngularJS uses the principle of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) where the building of DOM is handled by directives and fetching of data is handled by services. This example tangles those concerns. Please write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that addresses the concern of fetching data from successive XHRs.